# Creating a javascript array to localstorage not returning desired result

Tags: arrays

I'm trying to create an array to localstorage containing some gear box values, witch I then need again to do some more calculations with specific array[?].value.
The problem I'm encountering is that the created entry returns only 2 array entries, although all entries are there but the " is at the beginning and then at the second last entry and then before and after the last entry.
These are the values generated.
spd_Dev = `["202.391,172.876,120.451,102.601,85.173,72.664,61.701,52.706,45.116,38.510,32.326,27.407,22.910,19.536,16.585,14.195,12.228","10.401"]`
When I used to use a fixed array I've entered it as:

```
var spd_Dev = [202.391, 172.876, 120.451, 102.601, 85.173, 72.664, 61.701, 52.706, 45.116, 38.510, 32.326, 27.407, 22.910, 19.536, 16.585, 14.195, 12.228, 10.401];
```

So my question is how to write this values to localstorage and read again from localstorage so that I can use this values as an array.

This is what I'm trying to work.

```
var D_RatioId = data.truck.make + data.truck.model + "D_Ratio"
var G_RatioId = data.truck.make + data.truck.model + "G_Ratio"

var fGr = data.truck.forwardGears;
var gr = data.truck.displayedGear;
var Rpm = data.truck.engineRpm * 100;
var spd = data.truck.speed;
var T_Dia = 1008.3;


if (localStorage.getItem(G_RatioID) == undefined) {
    localStorage.setItem(G_RatioID, '');
    var fG_Rat = [localStorage.getItem(G_RatioID)];
} else {
    var fG_Rat = [localStorage.getItem(G_RatioID)];
}

var spd_Dev = localStorage.getItem(Spd_DevId);
spd_Dev = spd_Dev ? spd_Dev.split(', ') : [];

if (localStorage.getItem("i") == undefined) {
    localStorage.setItem("i", 1);
    var i = localStorage.getItem("i");
} else {
    var i = localStorage.getItem("i");
}
if (i <= fGr && spd > 0.5) {
    if (i <= fGr + 1) {
        if (i == gr) {
            if (RPM > 1450) {
                var G_Ratio = Math.abs(Rpm / D_Ratio * (Math.PI * T_Dia / 1000) * 60 / spd / 1000, 2).toFixed(2);
                var spd_D = Math.abs(RPM / (RPM / G_Ratio / D_Ratio * (Math.PI * T_Dia / 1000) * 60 / 1000) * 0.821932).toFixed(3); 
                fG_Rat.push(G_Ratio);
                spd_Dev.push(spd_D);
                i++;
                localStorage.setItem("i", i);
                var G_RatioValue = fG_Rat;
                var Spd_DevValue = spd_Dev;
                SetG_Ratio(G_RatioID, G_RatioValue);
                SetSpd_Dev(Spd_DevId, Spd_DevValue);
                localStorage.setItem("spd_Dev", JSON.stringify(Spd_DevValue));
            }
        }
    }
}

function SetG_Ratio(G_RatioID, G_RatioValue) {
localStorage.setItem(G_RatioID, G_RatioValue);
console.log(G_RatioID, G_RatioValue);
}

function SetSpd_Dev(Spd_DevId, Spd_DevValue) {
localStorage.setItem(Spd_DevId, Spd_DevValue.toString());
console.log(Spd_DevId, Spd_DevValue, Spd_DevValue.length);
}
    if (spd >= 0) {
    var spd_Dev = [localStorage.getItem(Spd_DevId)];
    var spD_D = JSON.parse(spd_Dev);
    for (i = 1; i < (fGr + 1); i++) { // Some more code dependant on the above results //
```

Comment: When you set or get items from localStorage put the name of item in double quotes "" ie: localStorage.getItem("G_RatioID") also when you want to check if item exists: use === null instead of == undefined.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm using a variable for the name, (var G_RatioId = data.truck.make + data.truck.model + "G_Ratio"), and I understand that if you use quotes on that, then only the "G_RatioId" will be used as the name instead of "KenworthK100EG_ratio".

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use LSM.js? it will make everything simpler. you can put the array as an array so that it will return the full array only, you will not need to use split(),

https://github.com/kevinj045/LSM_js

```js
var lsm = new LSM("G_RatioID");
    var G_RatioValue ["202.391,172.876,120.451,102.601,85.173,72.664,61.701,52.706,45.116,38.510,32.326,27.407,22.910,19.536,16.585,14.195,12.228","10.401"];
    lsm.set("G_RatioID",G_RatioValue);

    console.log(lsm.get("G_RatioID")); // it will return the full array
```